# CLOB data in Oracle not displaying /fetching completely

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to fetch out clob data from a table.

In ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER, when am trying to execute a query, its displaying "..." at the end beyond 3800 characters. Could you please help me here to fetch out complete data?

Ex:

```
select data_clob from sample
```

**Note:
I have tried to use dbms_log.substr as well. but still the error persists.
I have tried to set buffer as well but keep on saying its "skipped."**

So please let me know if anyother possibility.

Comment: Your title talks about "fetching" completely, but the question is about displaying. The data is almost certainly "fetched" in its entirety. Are you asking how to make SQL Developer **display** the entire string? One thing I just tried was to "display" a string of 4200 characters; I copied from the grid and pasted in Notepad++, which reports it as 4200 characters, so the entire string IS output to the grid. Perhaps it is not displayed in its entirety, but that's another matter. Do you really need the string displayed in SQL Developer, or are you using it in further processing?

Comment: I'm actually creating a dynamic query. My clob data is having "SQL query", am using this query and creating table from its output. I'm requiring it for a purpose. I need this "sql query" completely at any cause. Further am using "Notepad++" to copy and pase to create script.

Comment: Do you put line breaks ( chr(10) ) in your query text? I suspect if you do, if your lines don't become too long, and you copy from the grid and paste in the query editor (all in SQL Developer), it will work. It certainly does work if you paste into Notepad++.

Comment: Tried removing chr(10) as well. My data is bit longer than 4k so wanted to take all out of it. Even i tried exporting as xml, but its not working. still with "..." huh!!

Comment: No... my suggestion wasn't to remove chr(10). Rather, if you do have chr(10), you should be able to copy from the grid and paste in the editor. Even if in the grid you see .....  in the editor you should see the entire text, unless the text has very long lines (i.e. too many characters between two newlines, chr(10) ).